# Javafx - evento de click em botão, dentro de uma tabela, não funciona

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, javafx

Estou num projeto JavaFX onde precisei fazer um autocomplete em um input.
Temos alguns plugins que podem ser usados, mas o autocomplete foi tao simples que preferimos fazer na mão mesmo.

Aqui está p HTML:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome"/>
    <input type="text" style="display: none" class="form-control" name="cod-nome" id="cod-nome"/>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_addNome" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_pesqNome" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divNomes" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="position: absolute; z-index: 500; background-color: #ffffff; width: 93%; display: none">
    <table style="margin-left: 10px">
        <tbody id="tabNomes"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Basicamente, a cada keyup feito no input, nós buscamos em um historico os nomes de pessoas que contêm a string disposta. A partir do resultado, colocamos isso em um table abaixo do input, apenas com os nomes, um por linha.
Isso funciona bem, e está bem rápido. O problema é pegar o evento de click em cada nome.

Estamos montando a tabela da seguinte maneira:

```js
function montarListaAutocomplete(arrayKeyValue) {
    $('#tabNomes').empty();
    for (var i in arrayKeyValue) {
        $('#tabNomes').append('<tr><td><button onclick="selecionarNome(' + arrayKeyValue[i].value + ')" class="autoComplete" type="button">' + arrayKeyValue[i].key + '</button></td></tr>');
    }
}
```

Em cada linha eu coloco essa function no onclick passando um valor, no caso um id.

A questão é bem ai. A tabela é montada, os nomes são dispostos no autocomplete, mas assim que eu clico, ele deveria fazer algo (selecionarNome()), mas simplesmente não faz nada. Nem um console.log funciona.

Aqui está a função que limpa a tabela e/ou seta um display:none na mesma:

```js
function configAutocomplete() {
    $('#nome').on('focus', function() {
        $('#divNomes').css('display', 'block');
        nomeController.autoCompleteNome($('#nome').val());
    });
    $('#nome').on('keyup', function() {
        nomeController.autoCompleteNome($('#nome').val());
    });
    $('#nome').on('blur', function() {
        $('#divNomes').css('display', 'none');
        $('#tabNomes').empty();
    });
}
```

Lembrando pessoal, estou fazendo uma aplicação em JavaFX usando HTML, CSS, Javascript e, claro, Java.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu posso estar fazendo errado?

Comment: Cadê o selecionarNome()?!

Comment: o selecionar nome é uma função que está no mesmo arquivo. Falha minha não ter informado, mas a mesma não é nem chamada a partir desse autocomplete, ja testei colocando um console.log, ela funciona a partir de um button fora dessa div, mas dentro dela não obtive sucesso

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta com o código da função `selecionarNome()`?

Answer (score 0):

Se adicionares esta declaração à tua `configAutocomplete()`

```
$('#tabNomes').on('click','button',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (id) selecionarNome(id);
    else return false;
});
```

E mudares a `montarListaAutocomplete()` para fazer `$('#tabNomes').append('<tr><td><button data-id="' + arrayKeyValue[i].value + '" class="autoComplete" type="button">' + arrayKeyValue[i].key + '</button></td></tr>');` ele *tem* que funcionar.

---

Explicando:

- `configAutocomplete()` põe o evento por `event delgation` (isto quer dizer que, nao importa quando o elemento é posto na página, ele responderá sempre ao clique)
- a função `montarListaAutocomplete` declara o atributo data-id no novo botão que a `configAutoComplete()` precisa para chamar a `selecionarNome()`